# MCU Flash Memory programming in C

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, flash-memory

Newbie here. I am currently working on a project that involves saving password on MCU(NUC200LE3AN) Flash memory.

These codes works just fine. After writing it I am able to read the exact value of user_password1 even after the MCU restarts.

```
FMC_Erase(PASSWORD1_LOCATION); //u32addr 
if (*(uint32_t *)(PASSWORD1_LOCATION) == 0xffffffff)
{
    uint32_t user_password1 = "1234";
    FMC_Write(PASSWORD1_LOCATION,user_password1);
}

uint32_t ReadPass1 = *(uint32_t *)(PASSWORD1_LOCATION);

UART_Write(UART0,ReadPass1,4); //4 -> string length 
_UART_SENDBYTE(UART0,0x0D);
```

But I will be using uint8_t array of 5(including the terminating '\0') as a source in changing my password. Example:

```
FMC_Erase(PASSWORD1_LOCATION);    

uint8_t new_password[5];
new_password[0] = '1';
new_password[1] = '2';
new_password[2] = '3';
new_password[3] = '4';
new_password[4] = '\0';

if (*(uint32_t *)(PASSWORD1_LOCATION) == 0xffffffff)
{
  user_password1 = (uint32_t *)(new_password);
  FMC_Write(PASSWORD1_LOCATION,user_password1);
}

uint32_t ReadPass1 = *(uint32_t *)(PASSWORD1_LOCATION);

UART_Write(UART0,ReadPass1,4); //4 -> string length 
_UART_SENDBYTE(UART0,0x0D);
```

With this, I can write the password and read it as long as those fix values are there and those fix values are just for default password. After I changed my password as long as i don't turn off the MCU it could still be read which is not acceptable due to the MCU needs to be turned on/off. If I apply this and then restart the MCU, reading PASSWORD1_LOCATION returns garbage/null.

Is there a way to turn this:

```
uint8_t new_password[5];     
new_password[0] = '1';
new_password[1] = '2';
new_password[2] = '3';
new_password[3] = '4';
new_password[4] = '\0';
```

Into This:

```
uint32_t user_password1 = "1234";
```

I hope you know what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: first of all `*(uint32_t *)` probably does not work since it's not volatile so all those reads and writes that uses it would very likely fail. Also your `uint8_t new_password[5];` uses 8 bit big endian ASCII encoding, but `uint32_t user_password1 = "1234";` (BTW should be `1234` not `"1234"`) is 32 bit unsigned binary integer, native endian. Those two representations are not compatible with each other.

Comment: Seriously, you are provided with library function like `FMC_Write()` `FMC_Read()` `FMC_Erase()` and yet you wrote your own "read" function with regular pointer deference, and then ask people why it doesn't work? Why do you think it could work?

Comment: `uint32_t user_password1 = "1234";` --> `uint32_t user_password1 = 0x31323334;` and `FMC_Write(PASSWORD1_LOCATION,user_password1);` --> `FMC_Write(PASSWORD1_LOCATION, &user_password1);`

Comment: @user3528438 I made it "1234" because its a password which normally is a char. I mean I can change my password to "12AB". Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to store ascii values, you can simply translate it to its value in hex:

`"1234"` will be `0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x00`

To store it into a `uint32_t`, get rid of the null terminator and

```
FMC_Erase(PASSWORD1_LOCATION); //u32addr 
if (*(uint32_t *)(PASSWORD1_LOCATION) == 0xffffffff)
{
    uint32_t user_password1 = 0x31323334;
    FMC_Write(PASSWORD1_LOCATION, &user_password1);
}

uint32_t ReadPass1 = *(uint32_t *)(PASSWORD1_LOCATION);

UART_Write(UART0,ReadPass1,4); //4 -> string length 
_UART_SENDBYTE(UART0,0x0D);
```

Comment: how about if its in an array?
can i do this?
uint8_t new_pass1[4];
new_pass1[0] = 0x31000000;
new_pass1[1] = 0x00320000;
new_pass1[2] = 0x00003300;
new_pass1[3] = 0x00000034;

then 

uint32_t user_password1 = new_pass[0] + new_pass[1] + . . . .

Comment: No. You can do uint8_t new_array [4] = { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34 };